# Isolating Data while Web Scraping using python

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

I am trying to set up automatic Web Scraping from a website using python to store the html data and make a JSON file that uses a specific format. I already have the JSON file templet and have been able to get the HTML data as a .text file using BeautifulSoup. However I can not figure out how I can select specific parts of the data without directly changing the code. Is there something I can do or would it be necessary to plug in all of that data myself?
Thanks and below is the code I am using.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# need to automate page swaping but for now test
# need to inciment over tr class-2 ->class 895 page = requests.get('https://www.finalfantasyd20.com/bestiary)
page = requests.get('https://www.finalfantasyd20.com/bestiary/undead/abadon/') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id= 'main')
Name = soup.find(id='abadon')
# print(Name.text)
# Type = soup.find() not gonna work with how this is caus no header
Stats = results.find_all('p') 
for stat in Stats:
    print(stat.text)
    Str = stat.find(string='Str')
    print(Str)
```

I have tried a number of attempts to isolate the specific value without putting it in myself but have continued to fail.

Answer (score 0):

As I try, the print(Str) output nothing. Maybe you need this:

```
str_list =[]

for stat in Stats:
    print(stat.text)
    Str = stat.find(string='Str')
    str_list.append(stat.text)
    #print(Str)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I undertand you want to scrappe stats below STATISTICS header (h5).
As you see that below STATISTICS there a paragraph

and its childrens are you target:

```
<p><strong>Str</strong> 26, <strong>Dex</strong> 18......</p>
```

we could see this as a tree where p is the parent node and

```
       <strong>Str</strong> 
       ' 26, '
       <strong>Dex</strong>
       ' 18, '
        .
        .
        .
```

are children nodes

one solution is to :

1/ find childrens with strong tag and 'stat' string inside it where stat could be Str or DEX ... [ in your case stat.find("strong",string='Str')]

2/ navigate to its next sibling to extract the correspending value [ Str.next_sibling]

check out BeatifulSoup official documentation to find more https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=next_sibling#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling

here is a patched version of your code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
# need to automate page swaping but for now test
# need to inciment over tr class-2 ->class 895 page = requests.get('https://www.finalfantasyd20.com/bestiary)
page = requests.get('https://www.finalfantasyd20.com/bestiary/undead/abadon/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id= 'main')
Name = soup.find(id='abadon')
# print(Name.text)
# Type = soup.find() not gonna work with how this is caus no header
stats = results.find_all('p')
for stat in stats:
    # print(stat.text)
    # print(stat)
    Str = stat.find("strong",string='Str')
    if Str is not None:
        Str_text = Str.text
        # here is the value of Str
        value = Str.next_sibling
        print(value)
```

you can do the same for other stats.

Comment: THANK YO SO MUCH, this works perfectly. Many thanks

Comment: You are welcome , I sill urge you to check the official docs .